# SceneKit Steering

Tags: ios, scenekit

How do I make my node always go in the direction it is facing?

```
float tilt = _motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
[_player runAction:[SCNAction rotateByX:0 y:-tilt * 0.03 z:0 duration:_dt]];
//Make SCNAction to moveBy X and Z in the direction _player is facing.
```

Is there a way to find out what the SCNVector3 is that is 1 point away in the direction _player is facing?

Answer (score 1):

To get the location in front of your player.

```
SCNVector3 pos = [_scene.rootNode convertPosition:SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -1) fromNode:_player];
```